# How to insert a ENCRYPT function into MYSQL code

Tags: php, mysql, function, encryption

Been experimenting trying to get the ENCRYPT function to work in PHP code for sending data to a database. I want it to encrypt the password but i'm not quite sure of the syntax. So far i've got this but its obviously wrong?

```
('$_POST[username]','$_POST[productId]','ENCRYPT( '$password' )','$_POST[description]')";
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with a php function named "encrypt".

Comment: Don't. Your database should not be managing encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're not concatenating the strings with `.`.

```
'ENCRYPT( ' . $password . ' )'
```

Plus, who knows if you should be escaping those quotes with `\` or not, since you didn't show the beginning of your string in your code.

Don't bother though... your code is incredibly insecure and wide open to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar, or **you will be hacked** without doubt.  Also, don't use encryption on these passwords... uses hashes with salts, which are one-way functions.

Comment: I think OP has the query in `"` and the `'` are to "escape" the values

Comment: @kingkero Maybe.  Who knows with questions like these.  :-D

Comment: `ENCRYPT()` is actually a one-way function - it's an interface to the `crypt()` function. (That being said, it's still a really bad one-way function.)

Comment: @duskwuff You're correct!  Sorry, I was mixing it up with `AES_ENCRYPT()`.